Equivalent of SQL Server bulk insert for updates?
I've made extensive use of bulk insert for onboarding and similar tasks. Unless I'm mistaken, one of the main reasons this runs rapidly is that much of the work is done locally on the server as opposed to sending up a large number of INSERT queries.
Now I'm looking at a similar issue for UPDATE. We are collecting changes to different fields in different tables from a file of the basic form TABLE/FIELD/PKEY=new value. I do not find anything similar to a BULK UPDATE, and looking at previous threads here it seems the solution is to upload ~= 2000 UPDATEs at a time.
I built a DB with 30 tables. Using BULK INSERT I can populate 1k rows in each in < 1 second. I then wrote some UPDATE code using a 2k row limit (so everything was a single batch per table in my DB) and that took 300 seconds. This is not unexpected, each UPDATE includes a WHERE so this is going to be more expensive.
Am I missing a higher performance solution?

I usually do a json of the changes and then join the main table with an OPENJSON call to do the update once

Oh, that is interesting! Can you speak to the performance?

It was much faster for my case, but of course your mileage will vary :)

"Am I missing a higher performance solution?" We can't effectively answer that unless we see a sample of your table schema (including PKs, FKs, and indexes), the actual code you are running, and preferably the actual execution plan for the updates uploaded to Paste the Plan.

@TN - I mean "is there a built-in system similar to BULK INSERT that I should be using?" The answer appears to be "no"?

@MauryMarkowitz - Correct. The updates will need to be done using traditional DML. Typically solutions will load the imported data to a staging table, and then update the target in chunks of perhaps 2000 rows (as you already mentioned in your question). However, there may be ways to improve on that 300 second execution time. Prescanning your data to eliminate unchanged data before the update. Chunking your data in target table clustered index order. If you can do the updates in a maintenance window, dropping and later rebuilding constraints and indexes can sometimes help with mass updates.

Indexing, particularly excessive indexing and bad indexing, can greatly slow UPDATE performance. Have you tried removing unnecessary indexes on the destination table(s) and putting all your updates into a similarly indexed staging table?

No there isn't. A common technique is to use a Table Valued Parameter, or a temp table with bulk-copy, both of which should be fast to insert. If they are indexed then the resulting joined update should be pretty fast.


Am I missing a higher performance solution?

No there isn't. A common technique is to use a Table Valued Parameter, or a temp table with bulk-copy, both of which should be fast to insert. If they are indexed then the resulting joined update should be pretty fast.
You can also create a json of the changes and then join the main table with an OPENJSON call to do the update once.

Thanks! Just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something. I think I'll go with the JSON solution as it would solve another problem at the same time.
